# Не работает валидация с помощью интерфейса IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Решил сделать валидацию на поле Login с помощью IDataErrorInfo, реализовал интерфейс и условие, но в окне все-равно нет проверки на пустое поле? В чем может быть проблема?

ViewModel

```
public interface IDataErrorInfo
{
    string Error { get; }
    string this[string columnName] { get; }
}


public class Autorized : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public ICommand LogIn { get; set; }
    public Action CloseAction { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public static string LoginStmp { get; set; }
    public static string PasswordStmp { get; set; }
    public static string ServerSmtp { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> servers_pop { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> servers_smtp { get; set; }

    private string selectedServerPOP;
    public string SelectedServerPOP
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedServerPOP;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedServerPOP = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selectedServerPOP");
        }
    }

    private string selectedServerSMTP;
    public string SelectedServerSMTP
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedServerSMTP;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedServerSMTP = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selectedServerSMTP");
        }
    }

    public Autorized()
    {
        user = new User();
        servers_pop = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        servers_smtp = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        LogIn = new RelayCommand(arg => ToLogIn());
        ServersPop();
        ServersSmtp();
    }

    public void ToLogIn()
    {
        LogPass.GetInstance.Authentication(user.Login, user.Password, SelectedServerPOP);
        View.View v = new View.View();
        SendViewModelAdapter svma = new SendViewModelAdapter();
        v.DataContext = svma;
        LoginStmp = user.Login;
        PasswordStmp = user.Password;
        ServerSmtp = SelectedServerSMTP;
        v.Show();
        CloseAction();
    }

    public void ServersPop()
    {
        servers_pop.Add("pop.yandex.ru");
        servers_pop.Add("pop.mail.ru");
        servers_pop.Add("pop.gmail.com");
    }

    public void ServersSmtp()
    {
        servers_smtp.Add("smtp.yandex.ru");
        servers_smtp.Add("smtp.mail.ru");
        servers_smtp.Add("smtp.gmail.com");
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Login" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Login)) return "введите наименование";

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MailClient.View.Menu"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MailClient.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Menu" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="#FFAED5F5">
        <Label Content="   Почтовый адрес" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="73,103,293,189" />

        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Войти!" Command="{Binding LogIn}" Margin="217,233,217,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Login" Text="{ Binding Path = user.Login, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ToolTip="Адрес электронной почты"  Height="35" Margin="184,103,183,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy" Text="{ Binding Path = user.Password, Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="35" Margin="184,143,183,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Пароль"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding servers_pop}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServerPOP}" Margin="10,54,387,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Pop server"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Copy"  ItemsSource="{Binding servers_smtp}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServerSMTP}" Margin="10,23,387,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Smtp server"/>
        <Label Content="             Пароль" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="73,143,293,141" />

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном коде довольно много ошибок.

1. Интерфейс IDataErrorInfo не нужно создавать самому он лежит в сборке System.ComponentModel
2. Этот интерфейс реализует твоя ViewModel а значит что валидации на ее поля, хотя в твоей вью модели нет такого поля как Login.

   Вообще очень хороший пример как нужно использовать IDataErrorInfo есть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. Не относящийся к вопросу. OnPropertyChanged он зависит от регистра. А в твоем коде поле называется например SelectedServerPOP а нотификация идет по selectedServerPOP